# How can I add more dependencies to an already activated python virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, conan

Here's my situation. I am using a C++ package management tool, Conan. In order to get Conan, I use a `virtualenv`. After that, Conan generates a new `activate.bat` script that I can use to create a `virtualenv` for the new packages Conan just downloaded. The problem is that I already have a `virtualenv` running. I'd like to keep the existing dependencies from my original `virtualenv` and then add the new ones Conan got. It seems like I cannot call two `activate.bat` files at the same time. So, my question is how can I activate two `activate.bat` scripts? All of this  work is done through python scripts, so I don't want to do manual steps.

Comment: Are you trying to get your C++ and Python virtual environments to merge together?

Comment: @jcragun Pretty much. But both environements are not necessarily language specific. I have CMake on Conan. Basically, I have one running venv with one activate.bat, and then Conan generates a new activate.bat that I'd also like to activate in the same environement.

Comment: I think it's related to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/5157